# Hamburger menu - why is my code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to do a simple hamburger menu using jQuery or JS (I'm easy either way) but my code simply won't work and I can't for the life of me work out why.

It's structured as hamburger top left, logo in the middle then a profile and basket top right.

At the moment all I'm trying to do is literally get the nav list to appear on click and then I can style it however. I'm trying to do this using the .hidden class to display the nav as block when the burger is clicked.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
       <section class="header-section">
  <div class="header-container">
   <div class="header-content">
     <div class="hamburger-container">
    <i id="burger" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="header-logo-container">
       <h2>Logo goes here</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="header-profile-and-signin">
       <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-suitcase-rolling fa-2x"></i>
     </div>
       <ul id="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="search-page.html" style="text-decoration: none">Holidays</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="sign-in.html" style="text-decoration: none">Sign In / Register</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #999;
}

.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hamburger-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.hamburger-container i {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.header-profile-and-signin {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: block;
}

#burger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>

$("burger").click(function() {
  $("nav").toggleClass("hidden");
});

  </script>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least three issues in your code:

- `$('burger')` needs to be `$('#burger')` to include the id selector prefix
- Similarly, `$('nav')` needs to be `$('#nav')`
- `.hidden` in your CSS needs to be `#nav.hidden` so that it's specific enough to override the default style. I'd also suggest changing it to `.visible` to match its purpose, but that's purely a semantics issue.

The other possible issue is that you may need to add a document.ready event handler to your JS logic, depending on where you've placed it in the page. This will ensure the jQuery code executes *after* the DOM has been fully loaded.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#burger").click(function() {
    $("#nav").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #999;
}

.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.hamburger-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.hamburger-container i {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.header-logo-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.header-profile-and-signin {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#nav {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
}

#nav.hidden {
  display: block;
}

#burger {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="header-section">
  <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="hamburger-container">
        <i id="burger" class="fas fa-bars fa-2x">Burger</i>
      </div>
      <div class="header-logo-container">
        <h2>Logo goes here</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="header-profile-and-signin">
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-suitcase-rolling fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
      <ul id="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="search-page.html" style="text-decoration: none">Holidays</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="sign-in.html" style="text-decoration: none">Sign In / Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Knew it'd be simple - I've changed the id's now in the script and it's worked straight away. Thank you - really appreciate the quick answer.